# Fxcop Custom code designed targeting VS 2010 not working for VS 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, code-analysis, fxcop

I have written some code analysis rules and created a rule set file which contain some custom rules and some are  Miscrosoft rules. The rules were developed and build on MS Visual studio 2010 and working fine on it. When the same rule set I tried to use in MS Visual Studio 2012 custom rules fail to load without any warning.

I have tried to build same project targeting VS 2012 and used the same assembly with new ruleset but still custom rule fails to load.

Comment: I am facing the exact same problem. It seems that VS2012 (and even VS2013) doesn't honor that relative path for rules. The issue is posted [here as well](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/3540100-make-codeanalysis-in-vs2012-support-rulesets-conta).  Were you able to find any solution / workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

This is a referencing issue.

Your custom rule uses references to FxCopSDK.dll and Microsoft.CCI.dll. Their version changes every time a new Visual Studio gets released.

Where Visual Studio 2010 uses version `10.0`, Visual Studio 2012 uses version `11.0`.

You could add relative paths in your `.csproj`-file. This allows for instant rebuilding in each new Visual Studio version:

```
<Reference Include="Microsoft.Cci">
     <HintPath>$(CodeAnalysisPath)\Microsoft.Cci.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="FxCopSdk">
     <HintPath>$(CodeAnalysisPath)\FxCopSdk.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

Comment: Relative path is already added. I think VS studio is somehow unable to load .dll.

Comment: Load your custom rule project in Visual Studio 2012. Navigate to the reference and check what version it has detected. If it is `10.0`, you did not use relative paths.

Comment: @TUSWAY I guess he is referring to the custom rules dll not getting loaded. And not the FxCop or CCI dll.